# Why isn't my nav bar resetting after I click the burger and expand the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS/JS and I just tried to create my first responsive burger nav bar.

The burger is only supposed to appear below 600px wide and almost everything looks and works pretty well.

The problem I'm having is that after I use (click) the burger the first time and then expand the window above 600px, the nav bar doesn't reset to how it's supposed to look above 600px, unless I refresh the browser. If I resize the window back and forth before clicking the burger everything works fine.

My feeling is that there's something wrong with my JS but I can't figure out what it is. Can anyone help?

Here is my JS:

```
const header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0]
const nav = document.getElementsByClassName('top-nav-links')[0]
const burger = document.getElementsByClassName("top-nav-burger")[0]
const closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0]

function openNav () {
  header.style.height = '200px'
  burger.style.display = 'none'
  closeBtn.style.display = 'block'
  nav.style.display = 'flex'
}

burger.addEventListener('click', openNav)

function closeNav () {
  header.style.height = "100px"
  burger.style.display = "block"
  closeBtn.style.display = "none"
  nav.style.display = "none"
}

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeNav)
```

Here is the rest of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ux93rsgh/

Comment: You a) have responsive behavior thanks to CSS b) change styles using JS when a click is happening. Any change of type b) will not be undone by simply resizing the window. Unless you add a window.onresize handler and actually implement the behavior you want. One thing I like to do is have two separate menus with classes like `desktop` and `mobile`, then simply hide one of them using media rules. That way I can manage them completely independently. This is another approach to solving your issue, but not everybody likes duplicate code (you would have the HTML for the entire navbar twice that way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to do with the way your JS function is directly setting styles on the burger, header, and so on. I'll take the burger icon itself as an example to explain what's going on here, before I explain how to fix it.

This element, with class `top-nav-burger`, has CSS rules in your stylesheet, using media queries, that give it `display: none` above 600px width, and `display: block` below that. When none of your JS code has yet run, this works perfectly, as you have observed.

But when your JS `openNav` function runs, it does this:

```
burger.style.display = 'none'
```

and similarly when `closeNav` runs:

```
burger.style.display = 'block'
```

That sets an actual *style attribute* on the HTML element. If you inspect the DOM in the developer tools after opening or closing the menu, you will actually see this attribute on the element.

And this completely overrides the CSS styles you're using, including the ones in the media query - because inline styles always take precedence over stylesheet rules (except when the latter use `!important` - which you should basically never use, for reasons I don't need to go into here). Therefore, once you have opened or closed the menu, your stylesheet rules for the elements whose styles you've overridden there, will never come into play (at least for those particular CSS properties).

The solution is simple, and is what you should do anyway, not just because it fixes this bug. It will also separates your concerns better. Style rules are for CSS stylesheets, while JS should only determine behaviour. The only "behaviour" you want here is, to say, "when I click this button, open/close the menu". You can signal that open or closed state simply by adding a *class* to some element containing all the relevant elements, such as the `<header>` (although the whole `<body>` would do just as well).

So your functions in JS would become as simple as something like:

```
function openNav () {
  header.classList.add("menu-open)";
}


function closeNav () {
  header.classList.remove("menu-open");
}
```

This in itself won't have any effect, but you can then add rules in your CSS stylesheet for how those should affect the styling - eg:

```
.menu-open .top-nav-burger {
  display: none;
}
```

Which will ensure that the burger icon is never displayed when the menu is open, as you wish. I'm sure you can work out the details, and hope you understand why this is better. Firstly, it fixes your bug, by delegating everything to the CSS and not overriding it by using inline styles. But it also is better for separation of concerns, and code maintenance, because whenever you want to change the styles of menu elements, say by changing the height of the menu, you can just add/change it in the stylesheet (as you would for every other element of your page), rather than having to hunt for it in one or more JS functions.